# how to set different login and root password

Tags: login, password, root, users, user-management

I want to use different password to logging into desktop from what I can use for `sudo -s` or `sudo -s -u root` on terminal/bash. And also I don't want any additional users with different desktops(like windows). And I also don't want this to use to be able to even browse system folders and should only be able to play media and browse internet. Is there a way I can do this?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 with GNOME 3.36.4.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user with no administrative privileges. You can login with this user.

You'll still be able to use `sudo` with a password from another user with administrative privileges this way.

```
su administrator_name
```

Then you'll be able to use `sudo` with another password.